# Is it possible to constrain generic classes for specific methods?

Tags: typescript, applicative, fantasyland

Let's say I create a container in TypeScript. It could be any container but I'll use the following simple example:

```
class Container<T> {
  val: T;
  constructor(t: T) {
    this.val = t;
  }
}
```

Say I'd like to offer a function so that if I have two containers with numbers in, I can easily create a new container with those numbers added together.

```
class Container<T> {
  val: T;
  constructor(t: T) {
    this.val = t;
  }
  add(c: Container<number>): Container<number> {
    return new Container(this.val + c.val);
  }
}
```

However I cannot figure out if it is possible to make the above code typecheck. The problem is that all I know about `this.val` is that it is of type `T` (which is nothing). I'd like to somehow constrain the `add` method so that it can only be invoked on instances of `Container<T>` where `T == number`. Is that possible in TypeScript?

The above is just a contrived example. What I actually want to do is to create a TypeScript interface for applicative functors. An applicative function has a method that for `Container` would look like this:

```
ap<A, B>(c: Container<A>): Container<B> {
  return new Container(this.val(c.val));
}
```

So in this case I would have to know that `T == (a: A) => B`. More generally I'd like to be able to define this interface:

```
interface Applicative<T> {
  ...
  ap: <A, B>(a: Applicative<A>) => Applicative<B> // where T == (a: A) => B
  ...
}
```

Is any of this possible?

Comment: there is, have a look at the handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints

Comment: I've read the documentation. But it only shows how to add generic constraints to a function. As far as I can tell that does not solve my problem.

Comment: It's not possible to constrain t for a single method.

Comment: @toskv, if you add that as an answer I will make it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a restriction for **T** that applies on a single method. You can only have them at class level.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints to generic types.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
interface HasNumber {
    x: number;
}

class Container<T extends HasNumber> {
}
```

But you can't have constraints using the basic types such as number, string, bool...

Comment: That is not what I want. I don't want to constrain `T` for the entire class. I want `Container` to work for all types but for one specific method to only work when `T` satisfies a constraint.

Comment: You can make a single method generic. like so myMethod<T extends HasNumber>(x: T) { .... }